# Binding click function to all elements within an anchor tag with prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have html like this:

```
<ol id="test-ol">
    <li>
        <a href="http://example.com">
            <span class="myspan">test</span>
            not in span
            <span class="myspan">test2</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    ...
</ol>
```

and the following JavaScript (Prototype):

```
$$('#test-ol a').each(function(narrowByElement){
    Event.observe($(narrowByElement),'click',onToolbarClick.bind(this));
});

onToolbarClick = function(event){
    var href = Event.element(event).readAttribute('href');
    console.log(href);
    Event.stop(event);
}
```

Clicking on the non-span part within the anchor tag would log the right href, but clicking on the "test" part within the span would return null.

So how can I bind my click function to all the elements within my anchor tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Event.on('test-ol', 'click', 'a', onToolbarClick);
```

.

```
onToolbarClick = function(event, element){
    var href = element.readAttribute('href');
    console.log(href);
    event.stop();
}
```

For more details, check out the docs for [Event.on](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/on/), specifically the descriptions for the `selector` and `callback` parameters.

Comment: I suggest that `bind` is not needed since `onToolbarClick` doesn't use it's context and there is no indication that `this` is in use at the time of binding. In the OP's code the use of `this` might be a confusion with jQuery's `$.each` which sets the context to each element, here it will be `undefined` or `window`.

Comment: @clockworkgeek You're probably right. I've updated my answer to remove the `bind` comments to make my answer simpler.

Comment: But it should probably be  `Event.on($('test-ol'), 'click', 'a', onToolbarClick);`

Comment: @MOmann Yes, you're correct - either an element or an id string, not necessarily a selector. I've edited my answer. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
onToolbarClick = function(event){
    var href = this.getAttribute('href');
    console.log(href);
    Event.stop(event);
}
```

For prototype 1.6.0 and higher.

Comment: this.getAttribute is not a function - Prototype 1.7

Comment: Ok, which version of prototype do you use?